# Does Flask trim <datalist> items?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, datalist

Within Flask and using Jinja2, I'm calling a datalist but for some reason any option with a space is trimmed so "tomato sauce" becomes "tomato". Is this something Flask is doing or have I messed up the templating?

```
<!-- HOMEPAGE -->
<form type="text" id="homeForm" class="centered" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <input type="text" id="homeInput" autocomplete=off list="topps" placeholder="Input here">
        <datalist id="topps">
            {% for top in topps %}
            <option value={{ top }}>
            {% endfor %}
        </datalist>
        <button type="submit" id="homeSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

# ROUTES.PY #
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ToppingsForm()
    topps = ["tomato sauce", "chilli flakes","something else"]
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form, topps=topps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<option value={{ top }}>
```

add quotes outside of `{{top}}`

```
<option value="{{ top }}" />
```